# exception when using if statment in ant script

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

I am trying to compare the value of a properties variable with a string as following

```
<if>
    <equals "${mat.projectName}"="seal">
<then>
```

When done so, I'm getting following message.

> Element type "equals" must be followed by either attribute specifications,">" or 
>   "/>"

I'm using eclipse framework to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Read the manual first:

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html

clearly, from the manual we know for `equals`:

> arg1  First value to test
>   arg2  Second value to test

So it should be

```
<if>
    <equals arg1="${mat.projectName}" arg2="seal" />
<then>
    ...
```

I recommend you to read guides about XML first, and then, Ant's manual.

---

**Update:**

`<if>` task is not provided by Ant; it is provided by Ant-Contrib. So you need `<taskdef>`.

For example, I have ant-contrib.jar put in my project's lib directory (${basedir}/lib), so I can write the following:

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="lib/ant-contrib.jar"/>
    </classpath>
</taskdef>
```

For more, you can check `taskdef`'s manual page, as well as Ant-contrib's webpage:

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/taskdef.html

http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Yes I recognized it. Thank you. But even after changes I'm getting the exception :BUILD FAILED
F:\Projects\Seal\build.xml:308: Problem: failed to create task or type if                   Should I use any jar? 
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.

Comment: By the way, for the taskdef problem, you can easily use google to get the answer. Questions like this are very likely to get downvotes. So, always Google first.

Comment: @ coolcfan : +1.  You made the question some what useful and prevented its close vote

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what you're error message says...

> Element type "equals" must be followed by either attribute specifications,">" or "/>"

You want this:

```
<if>
    <equals arg1="${mat.projectName}" arg2="seal"/>
    <then>
        <yadda, yadda, yadda/>
    </then>
</if>
```

This is XML, so you need parameters with values. Take a look at the [equals](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html) condition on this page. It takes two parameters.

Notice the format of the `<if>`. The condition ends with a `/>`. The `<then>` is a sub-entity of the `<if>`, and the *if clause* is a sub-entity of the `<then>` clause. Notice that you basically indent twice.

If you're doing a not equals condition, it would look like this:

```
<if>
    <not>
        <equals arg1="${mat.projectName}" arg2="seal"/>
    </not>
    <then>
        <yadda, yadda, yadda/>
    </then>
</if>
```